# lpSolve - optimize function to specific value + 10% of a vector

Tags: r, linear-programming, solver

Imagine that I have a vector. And that the objective function was a certain value, say 10.

Where the values of my vector were neither larger nor smaller than 10%

```
fn.obj <- c(3,4,5)

model <- make.lp(0,3)
lp.control(model, sense="max", verbose="full")
set.objfn(model, fn.obj)#-8333550.82)

  add.constraint(model, fn.obj*(1-0.10), ">=",0)
  add.constraint(model, fn.obj*(1+0.10), ">=",0)

  add.constraint(model, fn.obj, "=",  15)

res<-solve(model)

get.variables(model)
get.objective(model)
```

> get.variables(model)
>   [1] 5 0 0
>   get.objective(model)
>   [1] 15

But I dont want to set a 5,0,0  I expected

3.3 + 4.4 + 5.5 ...something like that  = 15

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as: How do I alter `x=c(3,4,5)` in a "minimal" way so that its sum is 15? The answer is: multiply `x` by `15/sum(x)`.

Another way way to understand your question would be: What is the "most uniform" vector `y` so that `x %*% y = 15`? Since "uniformity" is measured by entropy, this would make the problem a non-linear problem, but it is still solvable in R.

Can you clarify your question?

Comment: thank you very much it helped a lot !  the point is that I have x = c(3,4,5) and a coef =  c(1, 1.2, 1.5) and then x%*%y  = 15.3 .. And i really want to set this number in 15. I'll try to look for a  non-linear programing . Thank you again for your time!!